# Vb.net and MySQL: Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i hope you can help me. Fist of all, sorry if my English is annoying, i'm not a native speaker.

I'm getting this error and i can't see what i'm doing wrong. I have a program that fills a local MySQL DB with data from another program that uses an OLEB DB. 
So it compares the tables and upload new data on demand. But i'm getting this error with only one table using the same Sub that i used with other tables.

> Unknown column 'lpedidos.serie' in 'field list'

The problem is that 'lpedidos.serie' exists indeed. So here is the code of the sub, please don't laugh, i know that maybe is extremely inefficient, but i'm just a noob.

```
        Public Sub notIndexedTables(table As DataTable, table2 As DataTable, tableNA As String)
    Dim temptable As DataTable
    temptable = table.Clone
    Dim tablename As String = temptable.TableName
    Dim myAdapter As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim SQL As String

    Dim newconn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    newconn = mysqlConnection()
    newconn.Open()

    SQL = "TRUNCATE " & tableNA
    myAdapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter()
    Dim command As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    command = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(SQL, newconn)
    myAdapter.DeleteCommand = command
    myAdapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows()
        Dim columnNumber As Int32 = row.ItemArray.Count
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Dim s1 As String = "("

        For Each columna In row.ItemArray
            i = i + 1
            If i = columnNumber Then
                s1 = s1 + CStr(table2.Columns.Item(i - 1).ColumnName) & ")"
            Else
                s1 = s1 & CStr(table2.Columns.Item(i - 1).ColumnName) & ", "
            End If
        Next

        Dim s2 As String = "("
        i = 0
        For i = 0 To (columnNumber - 2)
            s2 = s2 & "'" & CStr(row.Item(i)) & "', "
        Next

        s2 = s2 & "'" & CStr(row.Item(columnNumber - 1)) & "')"


        SQL = "INSERT INTO " & tableNA & " " & s1 & " VALUES " & s2
        myAdapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter()
        '  myCommand = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(myAdapter)

        command = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(SQL, newconn)

        myAdapter.InsertCommand = command
        myAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


    Next
    newconn.Close()
    newconn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Basically it takes the MySQL table (tableNA), truncates it (this procedure is for tables with no index, there is other procedure for tables with unique index) and fills it with the data from the OLEB table (table) and takes the column names from the temporal copy of the MySQL table (table2) (maybe there is no need to use the table2 in this case... but anyway).

Here is the exception and the value that SQL string takes when the exception is thrown. 
[image: exception]

[image: SQL string value]

And here is a screenshot of the table structure in phpMyAdmin.
[image: lpedidos table structure]

Comment: It looks like the table doesn't have that column when you connect from vb. Make sure you are connecting to the right database.

Comment: i don't think so, it works with other tables and updates them before the exception is thrown.

Comment: What is 'serie' in English? Is it French for "set" or "range". If so, it may be a reserved keyword issue.

Comment: Do you have several copies of the database? Any chance one of them is missing this column and has everything else exactly the same.?

Comment: No, the screenshot is from the database i'm working on... i'm pretty sure because it truncates the table correctly.

Comment: Have you tried that INSERT statement using phpMyAdmin ? And if you are passing an Int as serie why are you using ' ' (quotes)?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the New MySqlConnection you need to put the connection string in there and specify the database name. Can you show your connection string?

```
Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(myConnString)
myConnection.Open()
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then try another column name and make sure it isn't a reserved keyword.